# Browser throws error "Whoops, something went wrong" when insertin 10000 rows from xlxs file - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading an xlxs file with 10000 rows. During the upload process, the browser throws the error **Whoops, something went wrong**. However, when i refresh the page, it shows all rows on the xlxs sheet has been inserted into db.

What could the issue and what is the best way to handle or **optimize this error please ?

**Controller**

```
   $get_group = $request->get('group');
   $get_group = $request->get('group');
   if(empty($get_group))
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'No group has been selected.');
    }
    $explode_get_group = implode(' ', $get_group);
    $selectedGroup = Group::where('id',$explode_get_group)->first();   
    if($request->file('imported-file'))
    {
             $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();                
             $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
             {
                $reader->calculate(false);

             })->get();                 
            if(($request->file('imported-file')->getClientOriginalExtension()) != 'xlsx')
           {
           return redirect('/customer/view')->with('error','File Format may not be supported');
           }

       else{

       if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
       {
         foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
         {
           if(!empty($row))
           {
             $dataArray[] =
             [
               'name' => array_get($row, 'name'),
               'phone' =>array_get($row, 'phone'),
               'user_id' => Auth::user()->id      
             ];
           }
       }

       if(isset($row['phone']) == 0)
       {
           return redirect('/customer/view')->with('error','Failed to upload file');
       }

       //  if(!empty($dataArray))
       else
       {

          $selectedGroup->customers()->createMany($dataArray);                    
          return redirect('/customer/view')->with('status','Contacts successfully added');
       }
      }
       }
    }
     else {
   return redirect('/customer/view')->with('error','No file was uploaded. Please upload a file');

        }
```

Comment: For this kind of tasks it's better to use a Job in background.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I try to upload big files that need to be parsed I tend to upload the file and run a background task to handle the parse of the file. It could be that you are receiving a timeout error or such. Usually you should be able to see the full error in your logs. Another thing is to use a try/catch so you can catch whatever exception is being thrown and see from there.

Comment: It could be a timeout error. The script takes long loading when inserting. Even before the error is thrown

Comment: You should not have users wait for such tasks. I would recommend uploading the file, starting a background task and redirect the user and notify the user when the file is completed.

Comment: try to increase  php execution time using  set_time_limit(seconds);